# Time field (in the format '02:00:00 PM' ) not able to export from Excel to MySql

Tags: mysql, excel, time, sqldatatypes

[image: datatype-issue]

I am trying to export data from excel(which I downloaded form a different source) to MySql using 'MySql for Excel' plugin, but I am facing issue with the time field. The format of the time is out of my control.  I've tried with both formats(General and Time) in Excel. Still seeing this issue. Is there workaround for this?

Comment: What is the result of `=ISNUMBER(B2)`  (Where B2 is the field containing "02:59:12 PM")? If the output is FALSE, then you do not have time values, but a string.  A string can be converted to time using the function `TIMEVALUE()`

Comment: @Luuk It returned false. I tried TIMEVALUE(), but it is converting the string to some decimal value.

Comment: If you format that decimal value as time then you are OK.  Or you can use the shortcut key `CTRL+SHIT+@`

Answer (score 0):

1. Export it as a string, not a TIME.
2. in LOAD DATA, import it as a VARCHAR() into an @variable
3. use str_to_date() to parse it into the TIME column.